# How to override geocoders compass points?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, geocoder

I'm using the rails geocoder gem. I would like to override

```
COMPASS_POINTS = %w[N NE E SE S SW W NW]
```

with german compass points:

```
COMPASS_POINTS = %w[N NO O SO S SW W NW]
```

but I don't know how and where (config/gecoder.rb?) to do this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Create `config/initializers/geocoder_override.rb` and add `Geocoder::Calculations.COMPASS_POINTS = %w[N NO O SO S SW W NW]` in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/b5af9506a3462b57af0cecef597d2569e204c967/lib/geocoder/calculations.rb#L5-L11):

```
 ##
    # Compass point names, listed clockwise starting at North.
    #
    # If you want bearings named using more, fewer, or different points
    # override Geocoder::Calculations.COMPASS_POINTS with your own array.
    #
    COMPASS_POINTS = %w[N NE E SE S SW W NW]
```

So, create an intializer `config/initializers/geocoder_override.rb` and add the following line :

```
Geocoder::Calculations::COMPASS_POINTS = %w[N NO O SO S SW W NW]
```

Comment: When I do this and restart my app I get:
config/initializers/geocoder_override.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `COMPASS_POINTS=' for Geocoder::Calculations:Module (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  compass_point

Comment: Try changing to Geocoder::Calculations::COMPASS_POINTS = %w[N NO O SO S SW W NW]

Comment: Great, that works, thanks a lot! Could you please edit your answer above so I can mark it as answer?

Comment: Updated the answer.